# Can not copy RTSP streamed video in android using FFMPEG

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am developing an android application. In my application I wanted to **record live streamed video** using **ffmpeg** library.I write one code for record live streamed video but it does't work. It shows some error. If any one know this please help me.

This is the code I am used to record video

```
try {

            fFmpeg.execute(new String[]{"ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.1:6667/streamhd -acodec copy -vcode c copy"+String.valueOf(getCacheDir())+"/MyVideo.mp4"}, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                    Log.d("fffffff", "FFmpeg cmd success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    Log.d("ffffffffffff", message.toString());
                }
            });
        }catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w(null,e.toString());}
```

when I execute this block I get the following **error message**.

```
03-27 12:48:47.109 2042-2042/com.steelmanpro.wifivideoscope D/ffffffffffff: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                          built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)


configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-   prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=

                                                                          libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                                          libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                                          libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                                          libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                                          libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                                          libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                                          libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                                          libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                                        Output #0, mp4, to 'ffmpeg -i rtsp://192.168.1.1:6667/streamhd -acodec copy -vcode c copy/data/data/com.steelmanpro.wifivideoscope/cache/MyVideo.mp4':
                                                                        Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I founded the solution. In android you must pass parameters of FFMpeg.execute() method as String arrays.

use the following code

```
 String[] cmd = {"-i" , "rtsp://192.168.1.1:6667/streamhd" , "-fs" , "25M" ,  "-b" , "900k" , "-vcodec" , "copy" , "-r" , "60" , "-y" ,"-movflags","+faststart",""+getNextFileName() } ;

 try {

            fFmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {


                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String message) {
                    Log.d("fffffff", "FFmpeg cmd success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(String message) {
                    Log.d("ffffffffffff", message.toString());
                }
                @Override
                public void onProgress(String message) {
 }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.d("finish",""+fFmpeg.isFFmpegCommandRunning());

                }

            });
        }catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
            // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.w(null,e.toString());}
```